# javascript lightbox causes error when updating mysql table

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a comment-reply system for my blog in php. Comments are stored in a table called **comments(comments_id, comment, comment_date, user, flag)**. I use a script which displays comments and near to each comment there is a link called "delete" in order for the user to delete its own comment in case want to do so.

my php script for displaying comments is :

```
<?php

// ... above code

$comments .= $row['comment']; // comment printed succesfully here

if($comment_user_id == $session_user_id){

$comments .="<table border='1' style='display:inline-table;'><td><h2><font size='2'>

    <form action='deletepost.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='var' value='$comment_id;'>
        <input type='submit' value='delete'>
    </form>

</h2></font></td></table>";                 
}
?>
```

in order to delete a comment, I update the table comments and set flag=1, so my script will not display comments having their flag=1 in table. In order to do this I use script deletepost.php

```
<?php  

$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var']);

if(isset($comment) && !empty($comment)){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `comments` SET `flag`=1 WHERE (`user`='$session_user_id' AND `comments_id`='$comment')");
    header('Location: wall.php');
}           

?>
```

My script until now works perfect without problem and the user that posts a comment can delete its own comment without any error. The problem started when I decided to insert a lightbox in javascript, so that the user will be asked before deleting a comment. So I have changed my first script to the following:

```
<?php
// ... above code

$comments .= $row['comment']; // comment printed succesfully here

if($comment_user_id == $session_user_id){
  $comments .="<table border='1' style='display:inline-table;'><td><h2><font size='2'>

// at this point problem occurs when inserting javascript lightbox

  <a href = javascript:void(0) onclick = document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'><h2><font color=green size=3>Delete All</font></h2></a>
  <div id=light class=white_content>DELETE THIS COMMENT?

  <form action='deletepost.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='var' value='$comment_id;'>
    <input type='submit' value='delete'>
  </form>

<a href = javascript:void(0) onclick = document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'><div id=pading><button>Cancel</button></div></a></div>
<div id=fade class=black_overlay></div>         

</h2></font></td></table>";

}
?>
```

By using the javascript lightbox as shown above, when the user will press delete, a lightbox starts and asks user if wants to delete the comment. The problem is that now when the user press delete button, it is not deleting the certain comment but the last comment that finds in **comments table**. Probably there is something else I need to write in my javascript to correct this, in order to know which comment to delete (set its flag to 1). Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'deletepost.php' is getting the correct comment id($comment) that you wanted to delete.

May be that can be the cause.

Comment: if I do not use the lightbox in javascript it works successfully. I have tested. The problem starts when I make use of javascript.

Comment: probably in need to define something else in my javascript for not confusing it